# Regarding webgl’s ping-pong loop, I don’t know why I can’t use the new one

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I know that the ping-pong loop is set based on two set rendertargets. For example

```
this.fbo_material.uniforms.particle_time.value = this.accumulate_time;
this.fbo_material.uniforms.fbo_texture.value = this.fbo_rendertarget_1.texture; 

this.controls.update();
this.renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

this.renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
this.renderer.setRenderTarget(this.fbo_rendertarget_0);  
this.renderer.render(this.fbo_scene, this.fbo_camera); this.fbo_rendertarget_0


let temp = this.fbo_rendertarget_0;  
this.fbo_rendertarget_0 = this.fbo_rendertarget_1; 
this.fbo_rendertarget_1 = temp;  

window.requestAnimationFrame(this.create_tick.bind(this));
```

But why can't it be written like this?

```
this.fbo_material.uniforms.particle_time.value = this.accumulate_time;
this.fbo_material.uniforms.fbo_texture.value = this.fbo_rendertarget_1.texture; 

this.controls.update();
this.renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

***//here is new*** 
this.fbo_rendertarget_0 = this.createRenderTarget();

this.renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
this.renderer.setRenderTarget(this.fbo_rendertarget_0);  
this.renderer.render(this.fbo_scene, this.fbo_camera); this.fbo_rendertarget_0

let temp = this.fbo_rendertarget_0; 
this.fbo_rendertarget_0 = this.fbo_rendertarget_1; 
this.fbo_rendertarget_1 = temp; 

window.requestAnimationFrame(this.create_tick.bind(this));
```

In theory, the results should also be able to inherit what I used.

```
this.fbo_material.uniforms.fbo_texture.value = this.fbo_rendertarget_1.texture;
```

And why does it not continue to overlap once I set up a new one?

If I use two fixed rendertargets, the ping-pong effect will be successfully achieved, but once I use a new rendertarget, it will fail.
The result I expected would be the same as the fixed one.

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of framework. or object structure. If it's a framework, can you please include it as a tag, or mention it in your question? It may be relevant to an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because the ping-pong loop actually only converts the rendertarget, so even if the material is updated to the latest texture, it will still be affected by resetting the rendertarget?

Comment: Sorry, my framework uses vue.js but I think this code may have nothing to do with the framework, so I didn't give it a tag